# Pattern Recognition: $7 \star 8$ =?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, explanation

> The following pattern was given to me by one of my friends:
>   If $$\quad 5 \star 5 = 10$$ 
>    $$\quad 6 \star 6=18$$
>   $$\quad 7 \star 7=36$$
>    then $$\quad 7 \star 8 = ?$$
>     a) $54 \quad$ b) $51 \quad$ c) $30$

**My Thoughts:**
$$5 \times 5 = 25 \to 2\times 5 =10$$
similarly, $$6 \times 6 = 36 \to 3\times 6 =18$$
similarly, $$7 \times 7 = 49 \to 4\times 9 =36$$

> $$\implies 7 \times 8 = 56 \to 5\times 6 =30 \implies \text{option } \mathbf{(c)}$$

But my friend has told its answer as $\mathbf{a)\,54}$;
so, can anyone explain the relevant logic ...

Comment: There is insufficient information provided to yield a unique solution in this case.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Are you getting option **b** as its answer?

Comment: No, as 51 is odd. But a) and c) are equally reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break it down as the following

> 5x**5**=10 
> 6x**6** = 10+8 
> 7x**7** = 18+18=10+8+10+8

if you look at the number of groups of

> (10+8)

You'll see that in relation to the second number

> 5+0 = **5** , 5+1=**6** , 5+2=**7**

so

> 5x5=10 ( zero groups of '8+10' )
> 6x6 = 10+8 ( one group of '8+10') 
> 7x7 = 18+18=10+8+10+8 (two groups of '8+10')

if you follow the same logic

> 7x **8** , second number is 8 and 5+3 = 8 
>  so 
>   7*8 = (8+10)+(8+10)+(8+10) = 54

Comment: I see that this answer has been accepted, but it doesn't make any sense at all to me. It's essentially saying that you ignore the first number and take (second number - 3) "groups of 10+8", i.e., that the answer is 3*(second number-3). But that doesn't work at all for the first example, and you only make it "work" here by arbitrarily using 10 instead of 0 when you have "zero groups of 8+10".

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan yes you are correct; But until anyone post its another answer(with a better logic), this answer may be considered as a solution for **54** ,that's why accepted this answer

Comment: I feel that this answer would be more suited for 8⋆8 than 7⋆8